# Program doesn't append file using variables, but no error message appears

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python 3.4.2

I'm working on a quiz system using python. Though it hasn't been efficient, it has been working till now.
Currently, I have a certain user log in, take a quiz, and the results of the quiz get saved to a file for that users results. I tried adding in so that it also saves to a file specific to the subject being tested, but that's where the problem appears.

```
                    user_score = str(user_score)
                    user_score_percentage_str = str(user_score_percentage)
                    q = open('user '+(username)+' results.txt','a')
                    q.write(test_choice)
                    q.write('\n')
                    q.write(user_score+'/5')
                    q.write('\n')
                    q.write(user_score_percentage_str)
                    q.write('\n')
                    q.write(user_grade)
                    q.write('\n')
                    q.close()
                    fgh = open(test_choice+'results.txt' ,'a')
                    fgh.write(username)
                    fgh.write('\n')
                    fgh.write(user_score_percentage_str)
                    fgh.write('\n')
                    fgh.close
                    print("Your result is: ", user_score , "which is ", user_score_percentage,"%")
                    print("Meaning your grade is:  ", user_grade)
                    Start()
```

Everything for q works (this saves to the results of the user)

However, once it comes to the fgh, the thing doesn't work at all. I receive no error message, however when I go the file, nothing ever appears.

The variables used in the fgh section:

test_choice this should work, since it worked for the q section

username, this should also work since it worked for the q section

user_score_percentage_str and this, once more, should work since it worked for the q section.

I receive no errors, and the code itself doesn't break as it then correctly goes on to print out the last lines and return to Start().

What I would have expected in the file is to be something like:

```
TestUsername123
80
```

But instead, the file in question remains blank, leading me to believe there must be something I'm missing regarding working the file.

(Note, I know this code is unefficient, but except this one part it all worked.)

Also, apologies if there's problem with my question layout, it's my first time asking a question.

Comment: `fgh.close` did you forget the `()`?

Comment: Oh god, I knew it was something simple, but didn't think it's that simple. Yup, that was the problem, much appreciated for making me realise how blind I am.

Answer (score 0):

And as MooingRawr kindly pointed out, it was indeed me being blind.
I forgot the () after the fgh.close.

Problem solved.